# Swift SKSpriteNode class not registering touches to GameScene

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, skspritenode

I have a class where I want to encapsulate all logic surrounding it's touch.  However, I also want to pass up the touch event to `GameScene` so that I can remove other nodes, for example.  I thought `super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)` would work, but no dice.

I've also tried the `Delegate` pattern, but I couldn't get that to work either, and didn't like that approach, really.

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class LevelSelect: SKSpriteNode {
    var level:Int = 0

    init(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) {
        // init code ...
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        // logic affecting this class
        super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a node do something when you touch it or are you having trouble locating the finger location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The super class of a SKSpriteNode (super.touches...) is not a SKScene.

Also when you add the touches methods to a SKSpriteNode subclass they will only fire when the actual node is touched not the scene. It is usually used for things such as a button subclass.

If thats what you want you can try forwarding the touches straight to the scene. Each SKSpriteNode has an optional scene property (nil until sprite is added to a scene) that gives you access to the scene the node is in.

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
      // logic affecting this class
      scene?.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
}
```

You also have to activate user interaction in your SKSpriteNode class or the touches methods will not fire.

```
isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

A much easier way would be creating methods in your LevelSelect class for all the stuff that you need done e.g

```
 class LevelSelect: SKSpriteNode {
     var level = 0

     init(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) {
        // init code ...
     }

     // Started touches
     func didStartTouches() {
        // do something
     }
}
```

and than in your GameScene you can use the property you have created to initialise that class and call the method(s).

```
 class GameScene: SKScene {

   levelSelect = LevelSelect(x: ..., y: ...)

   ...

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
          // logic affecting this class
          levelSelect.didStartTouches()
   }
}
```

To call a scene method directly from your SKSpriteNode class(es) you can use the "as" operator to cast the generic scene property to your GameScene so you can call the methods in GameScene e.g

```
 class LevelSelect: SKSpriteNode {

     ...

     func callSomeMethodInGameScene() {
        let gameScene = scene as? GameScene // dont use as!, always use optionals (as?) when doing the as casting
        gameScene?.removeAllLabels()

     }
 }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This exactly answers my question! Thank you.  Follow up, is there a way to call a method that lives inside of that `SKScene`?  I tried `scene?.removeAllLabels()` for example, and it didn't have access to that.

Comment: Also, I wish I could upvote again for the username alone :D

Comment: Hey, yes you can call a method, you will need to cast the scene property to your GameScene. I updated my answer.

Comment: YESSSSSSS!  I love the internet.  Thank you for your help!